# jQuery slideToggle with multiple nested elements

Tags: jquery, html, css

I would like the below `.children` to `.slideToggle()` but I can't seem to get the `.children` element as `.find()` won't work, nor does `.closest();`

In short, it slides all `.children()` elements.

```
<li class="page_item page-item-18 page_item_has_children current_page_item">
    <span class="toggle"></span>
    <a href="#">Menu Item</a>
    <ul class="children">
    ..
    </ul>
</li>

$(function () {
    var menu = $('li.page_item_has_children');
    menu.prepend('<span class="toggle"></span>');
    $( 'span.toggle' ).click(function() {
        $('.children').slideToggle();
    });     
});
```

Comment: Did you try `$(this).siblings('.children').slideToggle();` You need to look at the siblings of your span. `.find` goes downwards and `.closest` tests itself and upwards

Comment: seems to work fine? http://jsfiddle.net/6j86G/

Comment: @KristofFeys i guess you missed "it slides all .children() elements."

Answer (score 0):

You're placing an empty span in front of the menu so there isn't a clickable area.  Try prepending your opening span tag and appending your closing span tag sp it wraps around the menu item.

```
$(function () {
    var menu = $('li.page_item_has_children');
    menu.prepend('<span class="toggle">');
    menu.append('</span>');
    $( 'span.toggle' ).click(function() {
        $('.children').slideToggle();
    });     
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just forget the span all together and attach the click handler to your menu variable?

```
$(function () {
  var menu = $('li.page_item_has_children');
  $(menu).click(function() {
      $('.children').slideToggle();
  });     
});
```

If you insist on having span tag, add some content in it so you can click on it.

```
var menu = $('li.page_item_has_children');
menu.prepend('<span class="toggle">Click me :D</span>');
$( 'span.toggle' ).click(function() {
    $('.children').slideToggle();
});
```

And that should also toggle the menu when you click on "Click me"

Comment: I need to be able to click the menu link :(